# How to update pipeline to run specific stage in a separate container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, containers

I have a pod templated with two separate container templates. One template is JNLP(master) and the (build) other is for the specific stage for the pipeline. What code changes are required in that specific stage (build stage) to run that specific (build) stage in a separate container?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario using CI/CD.
Instead to run the specific step, you can build a target step, tagging it with a different name, than you can run it.

Ex.:
Say your image name is just image, you can build the target step you want to run (lets say the tests step) with:

`docker build --target test-step -t image-test .`

Than, run it with:

`docker run image-test`